# How to exit one python script from another python script but keep the first python script running?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've a GUI and I'm running another python script from GUI script. Now if user enters incorrect values I want to show error message and stop right there. Basically terminate second script at that point itself and not do anything further. But I'd like the first script (GUI) to stay open. How can I do this? Return function may not be very useful here because return function just stops the current function. I'm calling one function from another several times. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

For tkinter you can use messagebox.

```
from tkinter import messagebox   
messagebox.showerror("Error", "Message")
messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Message")
messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Message")
```